# Python code gives 200-status code while it should be a 404 code

Tags: selenium, http, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, instagram

I've written an instagram bot to follow people. Firstly, it goes to profile by link then it clicks on follow. But after a while because of the http 429 error code, it says sorry link may be broken. I try to handle with using request.get and response.status_code but it always returns 200 (it means successful). How can i handle with this situation?

Here is my code:

```
   try:
        follower = driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
        response = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
        response2 = requests.post(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
        response3 = requests.head(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
 except:
        print(response.text)
        print(response2.status_code)
        print(response3.status_code)

        if response.status_code == 401 or 499 or 409 or 200:
            a=0
                while response.status_code == 401 or 409 or 499 or 200:
                if a==14:
                    a=0
                    driver.quit()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    chrome_options = Options()
                    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\merta\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
                    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
                    driver.get('https://instagram.com')  # Already authenticated
                    time.sleep(5)
                    follower = driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
                else:
                        time.sleep(60)
                        response = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/')
                        response.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

429 - too many requests.
use a proxy to avoid this error

````py
import requests

proxies = {
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403',
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403',
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403',
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403',
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403',
   'https': '127.0.0.1:403'
}
# just google "free https proxy"

response = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{i}/', proxies=proxies)```
````

Comment: can you give more detail about this ? I'm a beginner

Comment: it didnt work thanks anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).